# Angular array doesnt show the data when it has one record

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am using an `angularjs array` to store the `record data(table rows)` received by using the http.get rest API and printing using an ng-repeat. The problem is whenever there is only one record retrieved through rest API, ng-repeat doesn't print the record. ng-repeat only print the records when API retrieves more than one record.

```
 $scope.details=[];
  var lrequ = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: "https://example.com/execSQL?sql=mysqlquery",
    headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
}
$http(lrequ).then(function(response){
    $scope.details=response.data.platform.record;
    }, function(){alert("failure");});
```

this is my ng-repeat line,

```
 <div class="col-lg-12" ng-repeat="dat in details | filter : { product_name : textname} as results">
```

What is the problem?the problem is with ng-repeat or $scope.details array?

Comment: please mentioned your response in your question

Comment: Remove filter and try once.

Comment: You have put filter on your object maybe it is not finding any record after filtering the data.

Comment: no it is not filtering any data @sonusinghal

Answer (score 0):

you can use ng-if

```
    <div ng-if="details.length ==0>
    <div class="col-lg-12" ng-repeat="dat in details[0] | filter : { product_name : textname} as results">
    </div>
   <div ng-if="details.length > 0>
    <div class="col-lg-12" ng-repeat="dat in details | filter : { product_name : textname} as results">
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this i think it would help you:

```
<div class="col-lg-12" ng-repeat="dat in details track by $index | filter : { product_name : textname} as results">
   <span ng-show="$first">{{dat}}</span>
</div>
```